# MVC 5 | Error 400 Entity too large (Identity User has a lot of Roles)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http, model-view-controller

**Edit:**
Worked Solution for this:
Implemented this: SessionCookieStore from https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/22d2fe99c6fd9806b36025399a217a3a8b4e50f4/samples/CookieSessionSample/MemoryCacheTicketStore.cs

and added this to my Startup:

```
services.AddSingleton<ITicketStore, MemoryCacheTicketStore>();
        
        services.AddOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)
                .Configure<ITicketStore>((options, store) => {
                    options.SessionStore = new MemoryCacheTicketStore();
                });
```

I'm using **Microsoft-Identity Platform** and a **ControllerDiscovery** to seed Roles for every Controller Action in my Project. These Roles are saved to the database and can be applied to users to grand them access to every part of the application. Each Action in Controller have a custom Authorize Tag (example: [Authorize("BaseData:Home:Index")]. This works perfect fine.

Now there are **a lot of Controller Actions and Areas and a lot of Roles** being created on start.

One "SuperAdmin"-User is being seeded and granded all Roles automatically. Now to my error:

When the "SuperAdmin" logges in, this error appears (in **Production on IIS** only):

[HTTP Error 400. The Size of the request headers is too large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0fsF.png)

These cookies are send in the Request:

- .AspNetCore.Identity.Application
- .AspNetCore.Identity.ApplicationC1 (Size: 4KB)
- .AspNetCore.Identity.ApplicationC2 (Size: 4KB)
- .AspNetCore.Identity.ApplicationC3 (Size: 4KB)
- .AspNetCore.Identity.ApplicationC4 (Size: 4KB)
- .AspNetCore.Identity.ApplicationC5 (Size: 2,5KB)

How to reduce this cookie? Or maybe disable the cookie and check roles on Serverside?

My ConfigureService() function:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddIdentity<Nutzer, IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .AddDefaultUI()
                    .AddErrorDescriber<CustomIdentityErrorDescriber>()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options => options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero);

            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046239/creating-dynamic-role-based-authorization
            services.AddSingleton<IMvcControllerDiscovery, MvcControllerDiscovery>();

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new CustomBindersProvider());
            }).AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

        }
```

***Edit 1:***

Setting the **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters** key is not what I want, because there will be a lot more roles in the future and the MaxByteSize is limited.

Comment: Creating one role per endpoint seems like a bad idea. Roles must be copied to into the user's claims, which are ending up in the cookie. What you probably want is to build your own authorization using `.RequireAssertion`, checking the `context.GetEndpoint()`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-a-func-to-fulfill-a-policy

Comment: thanks for the comment. This is a very good point and I will look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may refer to [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-bad-request-response-kerberos#more-information) to troubleshot your issue, as your problem is having large cookie in the request as well, so what we should do is reduce the cookie size or increase the server limitaiton.

You may first try to clean the cookie in your browser(ctrl+shift+del to get a pop up in the browser and clean cookie), if this doesn't make sense, then you may try to open the register and go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters` to set `MaxFieldLength` and `MaxRequestBytes` with a big value. After setting the value, **don't forget to restart the computer** to enable the configuration. At first I set the value as 1, then I also meet the same issue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the max bytes are limited and I want to use more roles as now in the future and then the request cookie would be too big for fast loading. BUT this solution is a temporary solution for people who are not using that much roles as me.